# Using Maildrop with Ubuntu

Tags: email, evolution, imap

Due to a total burn up, literally, of my Mandriva machine yesterday I've decided to upgrade to a newer and better distro. I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and am slowly getting things back in shape again. I'm using IMAP with my local folders under Evolution. Prior to the crash I was using `fetchmail` and `procmail`.

For some reason `procmail` won't install which is too bad as it was working great for me. I've moved onto `Maildrop`, have it installed but I'm having problems finding examples of the `/etc/maildroprc` file.

I've reinstalled `fetchmail` and `courier-imap` and both seem to be running fine. Would anyone have any examples of what a `maildroprc` file should look like? All the sites I've looked at on-line just don't seem to help or else I just don't understand them

Answer (score 0):

**Preamble:**

I have been using maildrop for many years now to filter my mail (as [a drop-in replacement for procmail](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-ports&m=141634350915839&w=2)). My usage has been:

```
mutt --> msmtp --> GMail --> getmail --> maildrop --> mutt
```

My mail spool is a very traditional `/var/spool/mail/andrew` and my central mailbox delivery is to `$HOME/mail/mailboxes`. So a little different to your own setup!

Nevertheless I can give an edited version of my maildrop filter, which I have placed as `$HOME/.mailfilter` (whereas I see that you have chosen `/etc/maildroprc`).

**Filter example:**

Below is a modified version of my own mailfilter, as you have requested in your question, which has in its expanded form served me well for *many* years:

```
#-------------------------------------------#
#  maildrop filters for $HOME/.mailfilter   #
#-------------------------------------------#

# --> Some Variables... <--  #

DEFAULT=/var/spool/mail/andrew
MAILBOX="$HOME/mail/mailboxes"          
SENDMAIL="/usr/bin/msmtp"
logfile "$HOME/.mailfilter.log"
VERBOSE=9

# --> Filter / deliver mailing lists...<-- #

if (/^List-Id:.*ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org>/)
    to $MAILBOX/ffmpeg

# --> Filter / deliver Forums email...<-- #

if (/^From:.*forum@linuxquestions.org>/)
    to $MAILBOX/linuxquestions
    
# --> Filter / deliver old friends... <-- #

if (/^From:.*an_old_friend@une.edu.au>/)
    to $MAILBOX/an_old_friend

# -->  Send a CC on receipt ...      <--  #

if (/^From:.*@iinet.net.au>/)
{
    cc"!another_address@gmail.com"
}
```

**In conclusion:**

This is the *old school* way of doing mail and I hope this example of a working mailfilter will assist you to get your own setup working and perhaps interest other AU users in trying out the old ways...